# Encoding VBE Script in HTA while keeping x-ua-compatible

Tags: vbscript, hta, vbe

I'm using a HTA where I load an encoded vbs file via

```
<script language="VBScript.Encode" src="some\path\file.vbe"></script>
```

That works as long as I don't use `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10"/>` or `content="IE=9"` tag.
As soon as I use this, I can't access anything inside that vbe file.

I've tried to load the html file externally and use the meta tag there, doesn't work.

How can I use a *.vbe file and their functions inside a hta while using x-ua-compatible tag?

Thanks!